# Writing a python code that will enter newline commands correctly

Tags: python

I am trying to write a python code (lets call it script_A), that by itself will write another python script (Script_B), that when executed, will create a text file, with lines of python code in it, where each line should ends with a newline command. The problem is that entering the newline command into the code in script_A, causes problems,….

Here is my code:

Lines inside Script_A:

```
main=open('Script_B', "wb")
main.write("fo=open('textfile', 'a')\n")
main.write("fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\n')\n")
main.close()
```

Then, executing script_A, will create script_B which will contain the following text:

```
fo=open('textfile', 'a')
fo.write(‘text to be ended with a newline command
‘)
```

Script_B will not run:

```
File "Script_B", line 2
fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command
                                                ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings

Comment: the newline in single quotes will need the escape sequence character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
main.write("fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\\n')\n")
```

should work ... (note escaped \n inside command)

(note this is one of many ways to make your code work)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to escape the backslash.

```
main.write("fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\n')\n")
```

will give you

```
fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command
')
```

instead you should use

```
main.write("fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\\n')\n")
```

(note the extra backslash) to get

```
fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\n')
```

I suggest that you use raw strings instead, to avoid exactly this kind of problem. A raw string has a `r` character in front and will interpret any backslashes as actual backslashes rather than as escape characters.

As a raw string:

```
main.write(r"fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\n')\n")
```

(note the `r` in front of the string) will give you

```
fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\n')\n
```

The only problem is that you now have an extra `\n` at the end, which you can fix by instead writing

```
main.write(r"fo.write('text to be ended with a newline command\n')" + "\n")
```

This gives you exactly what you want and is a nice way of separating out the code -- which should be in a raw string to avoid problems with backslashes -- and the newline at the end of each string.